# Not available to fetch last modified date in AWS athena using Presto SQL

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

I want to write a query In AWS Athena which will give me the last but latest modified date in that column but instead it is giving me a date of years ago. While I know the latest date is around 2021 year

SELECT 'Direct' AS "ERP System",
'MYTABLE' AS "Table Name",
COUNT(*) AS "Count",
FROM_UNIXTIME(MIN("fetch_date") / 1000) AS "Data Available From"
FROM "MYTABLE";

I wrote this and I got the latest date as  1970-01-20 07:20:22
while the latest date in the column is 1.622421022179976E9  which is of Nov 2022 which I got using unix converter tool

Comment: Can you add some sample data for the `fetch_date` column?